# Find multiple scrape data inside the same <div> in python and beautifulsoup

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Using beautifulsoup its simple to extract a single data string from a div tag. But what if i need more results from the same div class tag? The number after "Refernece no:", Date after "date:" and the "RegistrationDate:" date?  That is three strings from the same div tag "right-col".

What would you reccommend?
 - regular expression?
 - possible to get more than one "sibling" using beautifulsoup?

```
<div class="right-col">
  <div>Reference no: 2017-598760</div>
  <div>date:<span class="label label-info">2017-12-15</span>
  </div>
  <div>RegistrationDate: 2017-10-29</div>
</div>
```

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: Is content inside of the main div dynamic? Number of divs inside changes? You could loop through content using beautifulsoup.

Comment: No. The content is not dynamic. It's all static information. But there are 10 "right-col" with different information on each page.

Comment: Can you provide us the link to the page?

Comment: Sure. https://www.doffin.no/Notice. I translated what's inside "right-col" div tag in english for you, so just be aware that what you see now is not english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transform each found `div` to html and then again find all sub divs:

```
divs = page.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'right-col'})


for div in divs:
    div_to_html = bs.BeautifulSoup(div.__str__(),'lxml')

    sub_divs = div_to_html.find_all('div')

    reference_no = sub_divs[1].text
    reference_no = reference_no.replace('Doffin referanse: ', '')

    print(reference_no)

    registration_date = ''
    date = ''    

    if(len(sub_divs) == 4):
        date = sub_divs[2].text
        date = date.replace('Tilbudsfrist: ', '')
        registration_date = sub_divs[3]
    else:
        registration_date = sub_divs[2] 

    registration_date = registration_date.replace('Kunngjøringsdato: ', '')
```

Comment: Your code works perfect! I struggled a litte bit to encode the non english letters, but by encode the "registration_date to utf-8 before replace it all worked out fine.